# Didn't fur out a shower pan

Tags: shower, tile

I recently installed and tiled a shower pan.  I did not realize that this particular pan needed to be furred out in order to install glass shower doors. Do I have any options or workarounds that would allow me to install glass shower doors without tearing down the tile? [image]

Comment: Furred out how? Do you mean so that the tile was on plane with the pan walls?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're hoping to install a swinging glass door set that would normally require that the tile and shower pan walls be on the same plane, with the problem being that the hinges won't align as you have it now. I see two options (aside from redoing your tile):

1. Install spacers for the upper hinge mount points. These could be made of faux marble or constructed with your tile so they match. They could be simply small blocks or essentially short walls that reach to the height of the door glass. If you go with small blocks the gap between the door and wall will be larger, but it may not be an issue.

Profile view:

```
|    |
|    |< -- door glass edge
|___ |
    ||
    ||< -- hinge location with spacer block (or stub wall)
 ___||
|    |
|< --|---- tiled wall
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|___ |
    ||
   <||- -- pan wall
    ||
    ||
    ||< -- hinge location
```

2. Order a custom door kit. Glass shops will be able to accommodate you with notched glass and/or custom hinges and/or chrome rails for above the pan.

Comment: Thank you. I will most likely be going with the custom door installation.